# Enable HTTP Request POST in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using Spring boot, here the maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

For the web pages I am placing the files in src/main/resources/static. There I have my html files, js libraries (angular, jquery), and css files.

I am trying to make an HTTP Request POST with Angular (I also have a GET Request that is working fine) but I get this

```
POST http://localhost:8080/xxxx/12/addEntry 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

In the Response Headers

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Application-Context: application
Allow: HEAD, GET
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 09 Jul 2014 13:04:05 GMT
```

I realize that in the Response the allow doesn't have the POST method.

The method in the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/xxxx/{uid}/addEntry", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String createEntry(@PathVariable String uid, @RequestBody  String form) {
    System.out.println(form);
    return "index.html";
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that Spring sees the controller? Do other methods from that controller work?

Comment: @axtavt thank you for your answer. the GET Request is working.

Comment: What if you try to remove `@RequestBody  String form`?

Comment: @axtavt thank you, now the POST Request is working. Your comments helped me to realize the problem. I wasn't sending the PAYLOAD in the POST Request.

Comment: could you answer your own question then?

Comment: @BrianClozel sorry the answer was in the question. I already posted as the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes especially during initial testing Spring's *csrf* - Cross Site Request Forgery - protection kicks in by default and prevents POST requests from taking place, a **temporary** workaround is to disable *csrf*. This is typically done in your Web Security Config class which extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Note: This works as on *Spring boot version 2.0.0.RC1* and its best if this **IS NOT** be used as permanent work around

Answer (score 3):

A different solution worked for me. I just needed to add the proper annotation to the controller itself, like this:

```
@RestController
public class EntriesController {
    //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a while ago, sorry for don't post the answer at that time, but I will try to explain what I suppose it had happened.

I was trying to test the ajax request with the plugin of Chrome Postman, but was not possible because I've got a CORS problem (I could not do the ajax with the POST method because the server only allowed me make a HEAD or GET requests).

In the same server I had the angular application (that was the application that had to make the POST request) and the Java API (that was the application that was expecting the POST request), so there, I hadn't a CORS problem. But it was not working because I made another mistake that was that in the post method of the angular application I was not sending the payload data on the POST.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/xxxx/{uid}/addEntry", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String createEntry(@PathVariable String uid, @RequestBody  String form) {
    System.out.println(form);
    return "index.html";
}
```

I hope this make the answer more clear. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer doesn't explain anything.

Comment: @SergDerbst sorry for that, I hope this explanation helps

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot has CSRF security on by default. When submitting form data via JS, you'll need to include the Spring Boot generated _csrf token when you POST to your endpoint.