# How do you update a single table column in spring boot without updating the rest of the attributes?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I'm developing a car sales system using spring boot. When a car dealer posts a car on sale, the car status is set to PENDING by default and the admin should approve the post. I want to update this car status without updating the other attributes of a car(milleage, price, model, etc). So i have tried using put but i get an error that POST is not allowed. Here is my code soo far. Any insights for something similar to mysql statement set columnName = newValue where id = id that my code is fetching using @PathVariable.

**Product Repository (for updating a single column)**

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "update Product p set p.status = :status where  p.carId= :carId")
void setUpdateStatus (@Param("status") String status, @Param("carId") Long carId);
```

**Product Service method to update status.**

```
   public void updateStatus( Long carId){
   productRepository.setUpdateStatus("APPROVED",carId);
   }
```

**Controller Method that is using @PathVariable to fetch the product id from view url.**

```
@PutMapping("/updateStatus/{carId}")
public void updateStatus(@PathVariable("carId") Long carId){
    productService.updateStatus(carId);

}
```

**This is my thymeleaf view part that is responsible for the url that i'm fetching the id from.**

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{'/updateStatus/'+${pending.carId}}" th:method="put" >
                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" />
                <button type="submit" id="Approve" name="Approve"> </button>
 </form>
```

I expected the id to be used to update the status to APPROVED. but i'm getting the error mehtod POST not allowed. As you can see from the above my method="put" not POST. I don't know what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Probably spring security is activated in your project, by default csrf protection is enabled when you use spring security, so you need to send csrf parameters in request header or deactivate the csrf.

**Here you can see how to send the header parameters:** [Spring MVC PUT Request returns 405 Method Not Allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719823/spring-mvc-put-request-returns-405-method-not-allowed)

**And here how to deactivate the csrf:** [Enable HTTP Request POST in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24655203/enable-http-request-post-in-spring-boot)

**Use the second option only for development!** You can make your application unsafe deactivating the crsf protection.

Comment: I solved it by using POST. PUT method is **NOT** allowed in html. i disabled csrf by using ``http.crsf().disabled`` but that didn't help. setting method="POST" solved my issue