# Request method 'POST' not supported at pass value

Tags: spring-boot

I use the interceptor in spring to make the user has login in,but when i transfer value from front end to back,the interceptor intercept the request,but it warns me that

```
WARN 8484 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved[org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]
```

and send me to "/error",but i have add the controller into the excludePath like this

```
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(cookiesInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/**")
            .excludePathPatterns("/adminapi/login")
            .excludePathPatterns("/Login.html")
            .excludePathPatterns("/index.html")
            .excludePathPatterns("/static/**");
    }
```

and the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/adminapi")
public class AdminController {
   @RequestMapping("/login")
   public String .....
}
```

the action of form

```
<form th:action="@{/adminapi/login}" method="post">
```

so i do not know why the problem occur

Comment: Please don't use images, just add the code as text in the question. (Just like you've added the warning)

Comment: OK,I have modified

Comment: Mentioning the request URL and Controller method will be more helpful

Answer (score 0):

In your AdminController,

replace `@RequestMapping("/login")`
with `@PostMapping("/login")`

This tells Spring Boot that you are using the POST method, otherwise by default GET is expected

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the `@Controller` annotation in your `AdminController`

By the way, you should specify the method for your `RequestMapping`, you can use

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/adminapi")
public class AdminController {
   @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String .....
}
```

or

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/adminapi")
public class AdminController {
   @PostMapping("/login")
   public String .....
}
```

Comment: it has the "@Controller",and i have test it with your methods , but it also dosen't work ,i use Terminal to print the form-value in the interceptor, it can get the value,but the servletPath is /error

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether CSRF is enabled in spring security xml file . If so add the

So you should be able to submit the model attribute.
Seems duplicate check here [Spring,Request method 'POST' not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699350/spring-request-method-post-not-supported)

2. Check whethr on the Controller receiving function for Spring MVC , you ahve this annotation. @ModelAttribute
3. For the requestmapping specify the method type .
   @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)

Comment: sorry,i dont use the spring security chain, i use the interface WebMvcConfigurer to add a interceptor ，should i use the spring security，i am a green hand,hhh

Comment: i have debug the doDispatch ,i found that mappedHandler = HandlerExecutionChain,and the mappedHandler's property handler contains allowHeaders  [GET,HEAD,OPTIONS],dont have post

Comment: a temporary workaround is to disable csrf and try whether it works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24655203/enable-http-request-post-in-spring-boot

Comment: thanks , i have solved the problem,i find  when the dispatch get the handler,it identify the request as a static resources request,and i change the thymeleaf form-action to normal,it goes to work!