# Passing a BODY of a POST request to the server

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, rest, client-server

I have built a Restful-API Java(SpringBoot) and created the needed requests.

The following request is a POST Request to add new Category.

I have tested the POST request by POSTMAN, and it working as expected.

I am building the client-side in ASP.NET 5.x.x.
Now the problem appear when I am calling the post request, it seems the API doesn't receive the data (@RequestBody category) that has been send from the client.

Here is a code simple of how I have created them
Server Side:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
@PostMapping(value = "/add", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public CategoryDTO create(@RequestBody CategoryDTO category) {
    log.info("Adding new Category Name: " + category.getName());
    return categoryMapper.asCategoryDTO(categoryService.save(categoryMapper.asCategory(category)));
}
```

Client Side

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Category category)
{
    Category newCategory = new Category();

    // Serialize the concrete class into a JSON String
    var stringPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(category);
    // Wrap the JSON inside a StringContent which then can be used by the HttpClient class
    StringContent content = new StringContent(stringPayload);
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
                
        using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://localhost:8080/category/add", content))
        {
                    
            string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            newCategory = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Category>(apiResponse);
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I don't know what is wrong there, could anybody help!

EDIT--
Here is the request via postman
[image: postman POST request]

---

***************************EDIT***************************

I have created another POST request but as a RequestParam instead of RequestBody

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @PostMapping(value = "/add", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public CategoryDTO addCategory(@RequestParam(name = "categoryName") String categoryName){
        return categoryMapper.asCategoryDTO(categoryService.addCategory(categoryName));
    }
```

and created in the client side the request as following

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Category category)
{
    Category newCategory = new Category();
    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "categoryName", category.Name } };
    var encodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://localhost:8080/category/add", encodedContent))
        {
            string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            newCategory = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Category>(apiResponse);
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And It's works fine!
So the problem is how to pass the data via the httpClient, which need to be of type RequestBody (the data in the body not in the header!) also as a application/json.

So how to pass the data?

Comment: Are you sure that you call the same url from Postman and your client? Do you have ‘@RequestMapping(“category”)’ on Controller class in Java? Seems like you send request from client to ‘/category/add’, but ‘@PostMapping’ has a path only for ‘add’

Comment: As you said on postman is working so your attention should be in your client .NET, postman can give you a curl code from your successfuly request, could you show us this curl created by postman for better helping?

Comment: @Zogger 
Yes, it's the same, as I have mentioned I have created a GET request and it's working, the problem is from the client side as I can't pass the body to the API

Comment: @DilermandoLima
Expected that, I have added a sample of the postman call

Comment: Have you received any errors in server side?

Comment: @Zogger An Exception for regarding the required field (Resaved it by doing the call from the Client side, not via postman)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your spring boot application just blocks POST request because you didn't provide instruction how to handle requests. Try to disable csrf protection like it did here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48935484/13314717

Comment: I Have tried to run the service without any security configuration, and also with the solution you have provided. doesn't work!
The problem not in the server, It's in the client side!

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem in the naming convention. Starting with capital letters in properties in C#, and starting with lowercase in Java.
If your class looks like this in C#

```
class Category {
    int Id;
    string Name;
    ...
}
```

And like this in Java

```
class Category {
    int id;
    string name;
    ...
}
```

It is not going to work so you have to match the property names. So make either both id or both Id.

Comment: Not the issue, the model are correct !